# set Excel Chart DataLabels position

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I have some excel chart object generated via C# code. Chart type is ColumnClustered. Every bar has some DataLabel generated via the following code:

```
_excel_chartPage.ApplyDataLabels(Excel.XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowLabel, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, true, false, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue, _misValue);
```

Now i want to move labels from above bars to below (below every bar).
To accomplish this task I tried to use this code:

```
Excel.Point _pts = (Excel.Point)_series_1.Points(1);
_pts.DataLabel.Position = Excel.XlDataLabelPosition.xlLabelPositionBelow;
```

This code is not working and some HRESULT exception appears, but where I use for example `Excel.XlDataLabelPosition.xlLabelPositionCenter` labels are moving to the center of each bar.

How to move them below every bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different types of charts support different label positions. The Clustered column chart for example supports these positions:

[image]

This means that you cannot use the below option, which is used for scatter charts for example. Trying to assign it to a clustered column series causes the exception you are getting.

I got these options by simply right clicking on the labels and selecting "Format data labels" (or Ctrl + 1 on keyboard). You can try out the different options to see if any of those works for you. And if not there are various hacks you could do. Like inserting an invisible series which is used only for labels That is what we often use.

Comment: Mitja, big thanks for Your clue. Going that way I made it that way:                    `_pts_series_1 = (Excel.Point)_series_1.Points(1);
                    _pts_series_1.DataLabel.Position = Excel.XlDataLabelPosition.xlLabelPositionInsideBase;
                    _pts_series_1.DataLabel.Top = 245;`